# Delphi webService that returns dataset Like a MS Webservice

Tags: .net, delphi, dataset

I made a WebService in Delphi XE to connect to my ERP Database and returns plains XML.
I made the client that consumes my webservice. All perfect, work perfectly with 1000 users.

From another enterprise they made same Webservice in .NET, and following my specifications, returns same plains XML and my Client app consumes perfectly both webservices like it was the same.

They have made another client and they have put others functions, at their webservice, thats returns .NET datasets.

Now I must implement the same functions and return datasets in same .NET style.

How can I do this?
How can I convert my datasets in XML .NET style?

TIA.

Comment: There is no such thing. .NET does NOT return datasets by default. Actually it is considered **very bad practice** to return a naked dataset, as it makes interoperability almost impossible and polutes the actual payload with lots of unnecessary info. An ASMX or WCF service should the proper data and operation contracts, map its data to these classes and expose them.

Comment: If they make up/start using some other exchange format they should tell you what the structure is. And you should tell us.

Comment: The format is up to you and the other developers to coordinate the structure. There is no built-in .NET structure in Delphi, because Delphi is not a .NET language. Just take a look at how this format is structured, and write something that interprets it.

Comment: There is no way that this question can be answered without more information.  Surely there will be no ready-built tool that can convert between two bespoke data formats and since you haven't told us anything about the target format we also cannot provide any guidance.  As it stands this question is `How can I convert XML to an undefined format?`.  The only reasonable answer is to start at step one - determine what the target format is.  If you know, you must tell us.  If you don't know then you must find out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not answering your direct question, but providing an alternative of a better solution.

The reason is that though it is not a good idea to return a plain `System.Data.DataSet` it is a pragmatic way to show a proof of concept.

> As a sideline:
>
> I've never found a `TClientDataSet` to `System.Data.DataSet` converter
>   or the other way around. If anyone finds one, please post a comment.

The "correct" way to do parse data over a webservice is define the structure of `XML` you want to return from your webservice to your client (for instance by defining an `XSD` for it), then use an XSD/XML mapping to return that `XML` from your Delphi webservice.

To get this working, Delphi has an [XML Mapper tool](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_XMLMapper) that can map from `TClientDataSet` to `XML` and back. [This article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28010) - though old - is still a good example on how to do that. Another great source of information covering this is [this series of book chapters](http://keith-wood.name/DelphiXML/BookCode/).

On the .NET side you want to map the XML to `System.Data.DataSet`. A nice article about that is [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/MappingDataSetToXMLAndBackwards.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot... this is the way i've in my head, but i don't knew how to do it... you show me the light!!!   many thanks again...

Comment: @JosepMaria ask these in new and specific questions like "I have this and this information that needs to go from a web service to a web client. How do I design an XSD for this". Then read yourself into the XML Mapper documentation, and start asking specific questions about that. Finally read yourself into the .NET documentation on mapping XML to System.Data.DataSet and ask specific questions about that. Show the people what you have tried, and they will try and help you.

Answer (score 0):

The xml shown down is the response of the other webservice made in .net

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
      <NotMyWS_Header xmlns="http://NotMyWebService.ServiceName/ServiceName/ServiceName.asmx">
        <Version />
    ...
        <mensageStatus>201 - Login KO.</mensageStatus>
      </NotMyWS_Header>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <ArticleBrandResponse xmlns="http://NotMyWebService.ServiceName/ServiceName/ServiceName.asmx">
        <ArticleBrandResult>
          <xs:schema id="ArticleBrand" 
                     targetNamespace="http://NotMyWebService.ServiceName/ArticleBrand.xsd" 
                     xmlns:mstns="http://NotMyWebService.ServiceName/ArticleBrand.xsd" 
                     xmlns="http://NotMyWebService.ServiceName/ArticleBrand.xsd" 
                     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                     xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" 
                     attributeFormDefault="qualified" 
                     elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <xs:element name="ArticleBrand" 
                msdata:IsDataSet="true" 
                msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" 
                           maxOccurs="unbounded">
                  <xs:element name="Brand">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="bra_id" 
                                    type="xs:string" 
                                    default="" 
                                    minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="bra_as_id" 
                                    type="xs:string" 
                                    default="" 
                                    minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="bra_name" 
                                    type="xs:string" 
                                    default="" 
                                    minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="bra_as_name" 
                                    type="xs:string" 
                                    default="" 
                                    minOccurs="0" />
                      </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:schema>
          <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" 
                           xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" />
        </ArticleBrandResult>
      </ArticleBrandResponse>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

I need to generate this from my Delphi Webservice.
My question was about if there is in Delphi any automatic way (component or something like that) to generate the body directly from a Dataset.

Now i'm looking for generate the XML from the defined xsd as tells me Jeroen Wiert Pluimwers. (thanks again)